# java string tokenizer

Tags: java, csv

What if I have a file that I am using a string tokenizer on to get values between commas. Its a csv file. Here is sample input:

```
test,first,second,,fourth,fifth
```

so how can i catch that empty comma? Right now its just pretending nothing is there. It doesn't even see that there is a place with nothing in it.

Comment: can you post the tokenizer code?

Comment: First: is this homework or a real-life scenario? That makes a huge difference in how the question will be answered

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSV parsing in Java - working example..?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843997/csv-parsing-in-java-working-example)

Comment: CSV parsing is way more complicated that it first looks like. Use a CSV parsing library, there are lots on the internet to choose from.

Comment: its real life. i needed a quick and dirty way of parsing the csv file. I didnt need a heavyweight solution so the first thing that popped into my mind was a tokenizer but the split works much better and probably less overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using String#split() would be recommended over StringTokenizer.

```
String[] s = "test,first,second,,fourth,fifth".split(",");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(s));
System.out.println(s.length);

// output:
// [test, first, second, , fourth, fifth]
// 6
```

Also, if you have much more involved CSV parsing in your code, if possible, try using an existing library like [JavaCSV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I am understanding your question correctly. I would use well-known packages like [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

The split technique works great, so long as none of your elements have a comma inside it. You can use existing libraries. I've also had good results using regexp for CSV processing.