# Split information directly from an URL

Tags: java, url, split

I want to read every Airport and corresponding airport code from each line of this [airport file](http://openflights.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/openflights/openflights/data/airports.dat), and then split the line by [,] so i can put desired info into an database.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com?

Comment: I downloaded the URL to an TXT file and then i read the whole file in as a string and tried so split it. But the content was to big i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader( new InputStreamReader(new URL( "http://..." ).openStream()) );
  String readLine = lnr.readLine();
  do {
     String[] split = readLine.split(",");
     for( String col : split )
     {
        // Write to DB
        System.out.println(col);
     }
     readLine = lnr.readLine();
  } while (readLine!=null)
```

You may want to use a CSV reading library, such as [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/csv/) to read the file. Take a look at this post [CSV parsing in Java - working example..?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/843997/221781).

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small sample in ideone to show you how to read line by line from a given stream and then split the line by a comma:

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String temp;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            temp = sc.nextLine();
            String[] strs = temp.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; ++i) {
                System.out.println(strs[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("===========================================");
        }
    }
}
```

I do not solve the whole problem intentionally so that there is some thinking left for you as well. Also I have intentionally kept the sample as simple as possible so that it is easier to understand.

You can see an example in ideone [here](http://ideone.com/e1QVky).