# converting csv to xls in java taking care of a column

Tags: java

I am working as java developer and i want to convert an .csv file to .xls 2003 format so that my csv will be converted into .xls file the structure of my .csv file would be like

```
REC_STATUS,TRADE_ID,SETTLEMENT_DATE,TRADE_EFFECTIVE_DATE,PAYMENT_TYPE,VERSION,BREAK_DOWN_BUCKET,CAUSE,NUM_CASHFLOWS_AFFECTED,PROFILE
Found only in File :B,178942690,01-Feb-16,03-Dec-14,"Coupon",5,NOISY_BREAK_BUCKET,REC_TOOL_ISSUE_PAYMENT_DIRECTION_MISMATCH | REC_TOOL_ISSUE_NOTIONAL_MISMATCH | TRADE_VERSION,1,AVS Offshore
Found only in File :B,197728700,Various,21-Dec-15,"Coupon,(x20)",2,ACTUAL DATA BREAK BUCKET,ACTUAL_DATA_BREAK,20,AVS Offshore
```

Now as you can see that .csv file is comma separated but for value  under payment type the value is like `"Coupon,(x20)"` now for this the value should be treated as single so the logic should be like that for the fifth column since indexing would be stating from 0 onwards so the position of column is fixed inside the .csv file so for the value of the fifth column payment type if the value is `"Coupon,(x20)"` then it should be treated as single do not split this fifth column value so for the fifth column value the logic should something starts from double quotes and end with double quotes  , so please advise how will i convert the .csv to .xls taking care of the fifth column value also

what I have tried is , shown below please advise how can i correct this code and overcome from the problem

```
public class CSVToExcelConverter {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
ArrayList arList=null;
ArrayList al=null;
String fName = "test.csv";
String thisLine;
int count=0;
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fName);
DataInputStream myInput = new DataInputStream(fis);
int i=0;
arList = new ArrayList();
while ((thisLine = myInput.readLine()) != null)
{
al = new ArrayList();
String strar[] = thisLine.split(",");
for(int j=0;j<strar.length;j++)
{
al.add(strar[j]);
}
arList.add(al);
System.out.println();
i++;
}

try
{
HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet("new sheet");
for(int k=0;k<arList.size();k++)
{
ArrayList ardata = (ArrayList)arList.get(k);
HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) 0+k);
for(int p=0;p<ardata.size();p++)
{
HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) p);
String data = ardata.get(p).toString();
if(data.startsWith("=")){
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
data=data.replaceAll("\"", "");
data=data.replaceAll("=", "");
cell.setCellValue(data);
}else if(data.startsWith("\"")){
data=data.replaceAll("\"", "");
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
cell.setCellValue(data);
}else{
data=data.replaceAll("\"", "");
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
cell.setCellValue(data);
}
//*/
// cell.setCellValue(ardata.get(p).toString());
}
System.out.println();
}
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("test.xls");
hwb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated");
} catch ( Exception ex ) {
ex.printStackTrace();
} //main method ends
}
}
```

Comment: Use a counter for the column. When you encounter the 5th column, simply read two columns and jump to the 7th column

Comment: @NikithaReddy Thanks a lot can you also please show a bit it would be great if you can please post the code i would debug it in order to grasp thanks in advance

Comment: @SheetalMohanSharma I have edited and added the code please check

Comment: You might want to implement or use a proper [CSV parser](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+csv+parser) that doesn't search for the separator character inside quoted strings.

Comment: @Kenney I still not able to grasp please can you please advise how can i overcome from this while reading csv in my above example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13655640/2378910

Comment: @Kenney Thanks can you please advise what logic should i correct in my above piece of code to overcome from this problem

Comment: Did you click my last link and read it? It explains it there.

Comment: @Kenney Thanks but please advise how can i connect that with my above piece of code please that will be really helpful Thanks inadvance

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class CSVToExcelConverter {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
         ArrayList arList=null;
         ArrayList al=null;
         String fName = "test.csv";
         String thisLine;
         int count=0;
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fName);
         DataInputStream myInput = new DataInputStream(fis);
         int i=0;
         arList = new ArrayList();
         while ((thisLine = myInput.readLine()) != null)
         {
              al = new ArrayList();
              String strar[] = thisLine.split(",");
              for(int j=0;j<strar.length;j++)
              {
                  if(j == 5){
                       a1.add(strar[j] + "," + strar[j+1]);
                       j++;
                  }
                  al.add(strar[j]);
              }
              arList.add(al);
              i++;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but please advise me for my above solution as i need to implement the logic in my above solution please

Comment: can you please explain what is happening in above piece of code and also please advise where is the output file location is mention

Comment: When the 5th column is encountered both 5th and 6th columns are considered and I added a "," in between.
Btw I just copied part of your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot let me try it please

Comment: You don't close streams, don't specify encoding (like me :) ), and use deprecated [DataInputStream.readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine()) — it is starnge to use it for reading lines.

Comment: @NikithaReddy Ok  :)

Comment: @NikithaReddy Thanks but request you to please post the fully incorporated code that will be really grateful Thanks in advance

Comment: what other code do you need? Did this solve your problem?

Comment: @NikithaReddy no please it did not solve my problem still

Answer (score 0):

You can use [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

```
 CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(
                new FileReader("c:/xxx.csv"), ',', '"', 1);
 // Read all rows at once
 List<String[]> allRows = reader.readAll();
```

This code ignores a separator - `,` in the quotes - `"` and skip the first line (`REC_STATUS,TRADE_ID,SETTLEMENT_DATE ...`).

If you don't need to skip the first line just use defaults (a separator - `,` quotes - `"`)

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(
                    new FileReader("c:/xxx.csv"));
// Read all rows at once
List<String[]> allRows = reader.readAll();
```

Comment: Please advise what is meant it will skip the first line with context to .csv file i have given

Comment: Probably a header line would be skipped

Comment: @v.ladynev  Thanks a lot but can you please advise also then how i will generate the .xls workbook as I am using poi 3.10 version and now I have all the data in the allRows array i want to simply put this in .xls excel file in similar fashion

Comment: @v.ladynev so i also please advise i want to read all rows and also the double quotes value as single so the final statement would be CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(                new FileReader("c:/xxx.csv"), ',', '"');

Comment: @sss Yes `CSVReader reader = new CSVReader( new FileReader("c:/xxx.csv"), ',', '"');`, but it is the same as `CSVReader reader = new CSVReader( new FileReader("c:/xxx.csv"));` because of this is default behavior  of opencsv.

Comment: @SSS so it will include my , inside the "  it would treat as a single entity

Comment: @sss Yes. Sorry, I don't have a code snippet for xls. Just ask other question about creating an xls from `List<String[]>`, but you will need provide code of your try.